# Convert a string to a key

Tags: c#, wpf, input

I'm trying to convert a simple string to a key, i've found a couple solutions but most of them are for winforms or they didn't show the complete code so i didn't understand it.

This is basicaly what i want to achieve

```
namespace KeyDown
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string CustomKey = "B";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            activeArea.Focus();
        }

        private void activeArea_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.CustomKey)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum in WPF:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

...

public Key CustomKey = Key.B;

// or this if you really want to convert the string representation
public Key CustomKey = (Key)Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), "B");


private void activeArea_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == CustomKey)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed");
    }
}
```